# ¿Cómo formar la palabra "glossophile" en Español?

Tags: contracciones

En inglés, hay una palabra muy poco usada, que refiere a una persona que ama los idiomas:  Glossophile, o el amor de los idiomas es [Glossophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossophilia).

Español también tiene los sufijos "-filo" y "-filia".  Pero no estoy seguro como traducir el prefijo "Glosso" del Griego "γλώσσα".

Mi mejor conjetura es:

- Glosófilo / Glosofilia

¿Estoy en el camino correcto?

Comment: Diría que sí. Lo "gugoleé" y salieron varias instancias que remontan hasta el 2006. Así que, con o sin el buen visto de la Real Academía, la palabra existe.

Comment: Flimzy, en lugar de "incomún", que es forzar la traducción al español de "uncommon" deberías usar "(muy) poco común" o, en este caso, "(muy) poco frecuente". Creo que ambos "common" and "uncommon" deben traducirse por "común" al español, y dejar que el adverbio (poco, muy, etc.) haga la distinción "common or **un**common".

Comment: @Diego También podríamos usar "inhabitual", pero estoy de acuerdo en que las opciones que das son buenas y tal vez preferibles.

Comment: Ya cambié la palabra, pero si hay mejor forma, les invito a cambiarlo por mi. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El camino o proceso para construir la palabra parece lógico. La raíz "gloso" significa "lenguaje" y tenemos palabras como ["glosolalia"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=glosolalia) que es el don de hablar diferentes lenguas (que Jesús dio a los apóstoles), pero hay que destacar que la psicología usa la palabra como término completamente opuesto: el hablar un lenguaje inventado carente de significado.

En español tenemos incluso

- Glosofobia: Miedo a hablar (en público).
- Xeno**gloso**fobia: Miedo a lenguas extranjeras.

Así que parece que existe la palabra opuesta a la que buscas (Gloso + fobia).

Desgraciadamente, pese a tener palabras como [bibliófilo](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=bibli%F3fila) en el diccionario de la RAE no tenemos "glosófilo".

La construcción parece correcta, y ya sabemos que el hecho de que algo no esté en el diccionario no significa que no exista. Además, al usar la raíz "gloso" no habría lugar a entender el sufijo "filia" como en "parafilia" (que designa un patrón de comportamiento sexual. Por ejemplo, la "gerontofilia" es el amor por las personas mayores: amor en el sentido de buscar pareja sexual de edad avanzada).

Sin embargo, creo que "glosofilia" o "glosófilo" serían consideradas palabras de "nuevo cuño". Yo recomendaría que donde las uses pongas el significado a continuación, para mayor aclaración.

Comment: +1 Estas acabando con el diccionario :)

Comment: +1, especialmente por ese *el hecho de que algo no esté en el diccionario no significa que no exista*. Es una palabra correctamente formada y perfectamente utilizable.